# flutter app gives SCUDO corrupted chunk header error during runtime

Tags: android, flutter

I have written a flutter app that works just fine except that it randomly give me Scudo ERROR: corrupted chunk header. I have googled for this but have not found anything that can help fix the error. I'm hoping someone can help me fix this issue so I can release my app.

I'm running on MacOS Monterey 12.6.3 and Android device Google Pixel 2. This is the output of flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.7, on macOS 12.6.3 21G419 darwin-x64, locale en-AF)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

And this is the scudo error

```
I/scudo   ( 4995): Scudo ERROR: corrupted chunk header at address 0x006e6ea5d770
F/libc    ( 4995): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 5031 (1.raster), pid 4995 (krit_vocab_isar)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/taimen/taimen:11/RP1A.201005.004.A1/6934943:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'rev_10'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2023-03-20 13:03:52-0700
pid: 4995, tid: 5031, name: 1.raster  >>> com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar <<<
uid: 10284
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'Scudo ERROR: corrupted chunk header at address 0x006e6ea5d770
'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000013a7  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000006deb9f8cd0
    x4  0000000000008080  x5  0000000000008080  x6  0000000000008080  x7  0000000000000038
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  00000070ef2337f8  x10 ffffff80fffffbdf  x11 0000000000000001
    x12 0000000000000030  x13 0000000000000018  x14 00001f9dbee4a387  x15 000c281a81169f8e
    x16 00000070ef2ccc80  x17 00000070ef2adf20  x18 0000006deb076000  x19 00000000000000ac
    x20 0000000000001383  x21 00000000000000b2  x22 00000000000013a7  x23 00000000ffffffff
    x24 0000006ddfcfeb30  x25 0000000000000000  x26 0000000000000008  x27 0000000000000000
    x28 0000000000000001  x29 0000006deb9f8d50
    lr  00000070ef2610c4  sp  0000006deb9f8cb0  pc  00000070ef2610f4  pst 0000000000000000
backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000004e0f4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+180) (BuildId: c78cdff5b820a550771130d6bde95081)
      #01 pc 00000000000429e0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::die()+8) (BuildId: c78cdff5b820a550771130d6bde95081)
      #02 pc 0000000000043088  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::ScopedErrorReport::~ScopedErrorReport()+32) (BuildId: c78cdff5b820a550771130d6bde95081)
      #03 pc 0000000000043154  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::reportHeaderCorruption(void*)+60) (BuildId: c78cdff5b820a550771130d6bde95081)
      #04 pc 00000000000446e8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::Allocator<scudo::AndroidConfig, &(scudo_malloc_postinit)>::deallocate(void*, scudo::Chunk::Origin, unsigned long, unsigned long)+328) (BuildId: c78cdff5b820a550771130d6bde95081)
      #05 pc 0000000001c1d820  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #06 pc 0000000001c1dd84  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #07 pc 0000000001c1d6f0  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #08 pc 0000000001c1cc2c  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #09 pc 0000000001e21d28  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #10 pc 000000000194f628  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #11 pc 0000000001945e8c  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #12 pc 0000000001958d90  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #13 pc 0000000001957d80  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #14 pc 00000000019585b4  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #15 pc 0000000001959390  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #16 pc 000000000195817c  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #17 pc 0000000001957ee8  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #18 pc 0000000001964628  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #19 pc 00000000016366f4  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #20 pc 000000000163bc30  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #21 pc 000000000001a064  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+916) (BuildId: b81fad2b6b7b7f85c6217d2cb80c9e61)
      #22 pc 0000000000019c68  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+112) (BuildId: b81fad2b6b7b7f85c6217d2cb80c9e61)
      #23 pc 0000000000012d3c  /system/lib64/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+100) (BuildId: 2912a009443ffd184dc729e510e384d2)
      #24 pc 000000000163bbb8  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #25 pc 0000000001636650  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #26 pc 000000000163a2bc  /data/app/~~HvDuJnU0-iXU-DUjUwAuzQ==/com.mikrodyne.sanskrit_vocab_isar-43fIlPWOgQCWTIgHWjVjug==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 8e449d2cb830f440b6d00cf6d20116687477e615)
      #27 pc 00000000000b0758  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64) (BuildId: c78cdff5b820a550771130d6bde95081)
      #28 pc 0000000000050150  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: c78cdff5b820a550771130d6bde95081)
```

Comment: any update on this, because I'm currently facing the same issue